# Populating Azure Search using a Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cognitive-search

I'm pretty new to azure search and data factory. I'm wanting to use data factory to populate my azure search index. I have the following:

**Source**

Azure sql db

```
{
"name": "Drug",
"properties": {
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureSqlTable",
    "linkedServiceName": "AzureSqlLinkedService",
    "typeProperties": {
        "tableName": "[transformed].[drug]"
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Minute",
        "interval": 15
    },
    "external": true,
    "policy": {}
}
```

}

Table structure

```
[DrugSearchId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[SearchTerm] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[ProdCode] [int] NULL,
[FormCode] [int] NULL,
[PackCode] [int] NOT NULL,
[PackSort] [int] NULL,
[Active] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[ActiveUnits] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[UnitsPerPack] [int] NOT NULL,
[NoOfPacks] [int] NOT NULL,
[NoOfRepeats] [int] NULL,
[PbsCode] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
[PbsDesc] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Product] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[GenericList] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[ActionList] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[MedicineInformationType] [nchar](50) NOT NULL
```

**Target**

```
{
"name": "DrugSearchIndex",
"properties": {
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureSearchIndex",
    "linkedServiceName": "AzureSearchLinkedService",
    "typeProperties": {
        "indexName": "drug"
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Minute",
        "interval": 15
    }
}
```

}

[image]

I'm getting an error when the pipeline runs with the following:

Source column names don't match with the Azure Search Index field names. Please specify Column Mapping.,Source...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the reason for error is case mismatch between the field names in the table and in the search index. All field names in the table are Pascal-case, while index fields are camel-case.